# Python flask web app- ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python-3.x, flask, client-server, python-sockets, gdata-python-client

aceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
conn = connection.create_connection(
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

why is it not making the connection